# Ignite's cache methods hang

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.7.6 and sometimes it hangs on calling cache's methods like TryGet or MoveNext for cache's enumerator.

I have one server and multiple client nodes, the hang occurs on the client-side.

Typical call stack:

> Apache.Ignite.Core.dll!Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.Env.CallVoidMethod(Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.GlobalRef obj, System.IntPtr methodId, long* argsPtr) Line 213  C#
>       Apache.Ignite.Core.dll!Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedUtils.TargetOutStream(Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.GlobalRef target, int opType, long memPtr) Line 145   C#
>       Apache.Ignite.Core.dll!Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.PlatformJniTarget.OutStream(int type, System.Func readAction) Line 147  C#
>       Apache.Ignite.Core.dll!Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.PlatformTargetAdapter.DoInOp(int type, System.Func action) Line 193 C#
>       Apache.Ignite.Core.dll!Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.CacheEnumerator.MoveNext() Line 55   C#
>       Apache.Ignite.Core.dll!Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.CacheEnumeratorProxy.MoveNext() Line 71  C#
>       AlphaLib.dll!Casino.Table.Enumerator.MoveNext() Line 503   C#

It hangs in CallVoidMethod. I tried to reproduce this on a simple project but failed.

This reproduces much more often if I start the client on the machine where the server node was started.

Any assumptions about why this happens?

**ADDED**

I inspected JVM state in case of hanging, here is the full stack: https://pastebin.com/v5HiuQWb
Looks like this thread is stuck:

```
"Thread-11" #148 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000001ae99665800 nid=0x34c4 in Object.wait() [0x00000050156bc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.internalIterator(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:301)
        - locked <0x00000005d494de98> (a org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryFuture)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.next(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:158)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$5.onHasNext(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:642)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.query.PlatformAbstractQueryCursor.processOutStream(PlatformAbstractQueryCursor.java:92)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.outStream(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:93)
```

It seems like this code hangs:

```
        long waitTime = timeout == 0 ? Long.MAX_VALUE : timeout - (U.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

        if (waitTime <= 0) {
            it = Collections.<R>emptyList().iterator();

            break;
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                if (queue.isEmpty() && !isDone())
                    wait(waitTime); /* HERE!!! */
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                throw new IgniteCheckedException("Query was interrupted: " + qry, e);
            }
        }
```

I suppose that timeout is 0 in my case, so it waits infinitely, so it's possible to set it to a finite value. But it doesn't look like a good solution.

Comment: Do you use async methods? Or it's completely synchronous?

Comment: Both, sync and async, methods have this issue.

Comment: Could be related to default thread pools http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Replace-or-Put-after-PutAsync-causes-Ignite-to-hang-td27871.html#a28051. Is there any chance to get a java thread dump?

Comment: Do you mean a thread dump for the client's application? I'll do it

Comment: I added some info about JVM state during hanging

Comment: So it hands waiting for a server response. Have you checked server threads?

Comment: Reasonably :) I'll check it

Answer (score 0):

In our network, there is a Symantec protection system, that unexpectedly started closing ports that were used by Ignite. On both client and server sides. Furthermore, it was starting to close these ports after some event or time after launching - I didn't understand. I found it in the Symantec log.

After adding used ports to the white list the problem was solved.